# How to trigger quartz job from a rest controller in spring boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have a controller where I'm trying to trigger new job immediately:

```
 @GetMapping("/job/{tripId}")
    public void handle(@PathVariable("tripId") Integer fundId) {        
                    
        SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
         try {
        Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();               
         //Create a new Job 
        JobKey jobKey = JobKey.jobKey("Trip Calculations", "Trip Calculations Group");
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TripCalculationsJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey).storeDurably().build();
        job.getJobDataMap().put("tripId", fundId);                      

        //Register this job to the scheduler
        sched.addJob(job, true);

        sched.triggerJob(jobKey);
        
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        log.error("Error when execting job");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                             
        
    }
```

And the job is simple class which implements Job:

```
@Slf4j
public class TripCalculationsJob implements Job {
                
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
                                                   
        log.info( "blah blah blah");
    }
```

The job is not triggered, here are the maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>         
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
             <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
          </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole point of having scheduled jobs is not to have them triggered manually. Why don't you extract what the job does to another handler class and invoke that from both the job and the controller?

Comment: The requirement is to execute asynchronous

Comment: I understand. Have you considered using regular async patterns then? You could take a look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/ and then make your endpoint return a `CompletableFuture`

Comment: calling from the controller to service with method annotated with @Async is the only solution to move forward I thing yes